# Understanding BigInteger constructor

Tags: java, biginteger

I have the following code from my textbook for figuring out factorial:

```
 import java.math.*;
 public class LargeFactorial {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("50! is \n" + factorial(50));
  }  public static BigInteger factorial(long n) {
      BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
          result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(i +""));
      return result;
      }
```

However, I really don't understand `new BigInteger(i +"")`. Why they put `+""` in the constructor?I mean we are not multiplying an empty String and it does not make any sense either.Please explain.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `n` as a `long` and `i` as an `int` if `i` is incremented right up to the value of `n`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just calling the `BigInteger(String)` constructor, because there isn't a constructor taking an `int`. Using string concatenation is a nasty way of converting an `int` to a `String`, but it will work.

A cleaner approach IMO would be to use `BigInteger.valueOf(long)`:

```
result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

(Given both of these issues, I'd be slightly wary of the quality of your textbook...)

Comment: I wish I could like your answer but I'm way down in reputation.Anyways,my book is " Introduction to Java Programming,
Y. Daniel Liang". I hate this book too,it's so confusing.Can you recommend me a better book?

Comment: *Why* isn't there a constructor taking an int? It seems incredibly useful. Similarly, why doesn't valueOf take a String?

Comment: @AbhishekDivekar I'm wondering the same thing 4 years later... There should be a constructor that takes int/long and valueOf should take the same options (they're virtually the same)